# Right click inside WKWebView reset text selection in Mac Catalyst

Tags: html, swift, webkit, mac-catalyst

Context menu in WKWebView reset text selection in Mac Catalyst, but should not. Any hacks to fix it?

What is problem looks like:
[image: Right click inside WKWebView reset text selection in Mac Catalyst]

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    let webView = WKWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let sa = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sa.topAnchor),
            webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sa.leadingAnchor),
            webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sa.trailingAnchor),
            webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sa.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html") {
            webView.loadFileURL(filePath, allowingReadAccessTo: filePath.deletingLastPathComponent())
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div contenteditable>Right click reset context menu reset text selection in WKWebView</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Reproduces only with contenteditable="true" property.